# How to properly handle intents in xamarin

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin

At the moment I am using firebase messaging for my push notification. I am attaching data to my intent so I can capture it and my application can use that data when the push is clicked.

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    public override void HandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        CreateNotification(intent);
    }

    private void CreateNotification(Object e)
    {

            var i = e as Intent;
            var bundle = i.Extras;
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));

            var notificationName = bundle.GetString("notificationName");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(notificationName))
            {
                intent.PutExtra("notificationName", notificationName);
            }

            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
            builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon_notification);
            builder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.icon));                
            builder.SetContentText(body);
            builder.SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound);
            builder.SetAutoCancel(true);
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                builder.SetChannelId("YourChannelID");
            }

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);

            notificationManager.Notify(1, builder.Build());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Then on my MainActivity Side of the program, OnCreate is triggered when the application is launched back into the foreground.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
     ....
     App.NotificationName = Intent.GetStringExtra("notificationName");
     ....
}
```

The issue I am having now is that one one of my device (Android 7 OS) it works as intended, OnCreate is triggered when the application is brought to the foreground. The issue I am having now is that OnCreate isn't triggered on my other device (Android 8 OS). Whats the best way to handle this intents and where should I put this code `App.NotificationName = Intent.GetStringExtra("notificationName");` so that it'll trigger on any device

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754149/android-xamarin-make-push-notification-not-create-a-new-activity-but-use-the-cur / https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood I guess you should use OnMessageReceived then you'll be able to get your notification using by GetNotification():

```
public override async void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
{
    var fromNotification = message.GetNotification();
    //...use message.Data and prepare the notification to notify
}
```

Of cource the approach depends on your remote notification payload ([Notification or Data messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options))

Also you can use ActivityFlags.NewTask while creating the notification:

```
intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainPage));
        flags = PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent;
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
```

But you will have to create your MainActivity as LaunchMode.SingleTop and will able to handle notification toast taps at OnNewIntent(Intent intent) and OnCreate(Bundle bundle) using by Intent instance from those overriden methods. (For OnCreate you should use Intent property of your Activity)